# ruby convert partial string to date

Tags: ruby

I have a string in the format

```
"01-2014"
```

Where the 01 represents the month and the 2014 the year. This is information about a credit card and is the month and year in which the card expires.

I need to be able to return all records where the card is expiring this month.

Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Your title doesn't represents your need.Please tell me what do you want exactly.

Comment: Could you add information about your "records", please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date.strptime("01-2014", "%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below :

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime("01-2014", "%m-%Y")
# => #<Date: 2014-01-01 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)

> %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least)
>               -0001, 0000, 1995, 2009, 14292, etc.
>
> %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)